# Why the smartwatch connected to the phone does not respond in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have paired pixel 4 API 31 with Wear OS Large Round API 30 in Android studio. In device manager beside names od device there is an icon which says: Paired and conneceted.

Also in Wear OS app on Pixel 4, it says: Emulator, Connected via Bluetooth.

For example if I try to change watch face, i click three dots and i click set on watch

but nothing happens...

Also i have tried to take screenshot of watch in Wear OS app on Pixel 4. after i click that

msg comes: Screenshoot request sent. and I hear some sound

but again nothing happens on the watch...

the only thing which works, if I click extended controls, and for example i click

Phone, and I click send msg. This works as msg normally comes also on smartwatch

and if I reply to this msg from smartwatch, this also works...

Please can you help me why other functions are not working ?

Do I need to edit some other settings or what ?

Thank you